# How do I keep a calculator in bootstrap with fixed with while still beeing responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a calculator in bootstrap. The design for small devices is as follows:

[calculator on small devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ8V3.png)

But when i change the screen size to bigger size, it stays like this:

[calculator on larger screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQar1.png)

The calculator needs to maintain the size it has on small screens in larger screens while still beeing responsive.

```
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="card container-fluid">
```

-My main container with a 8 col card (which is where the calculator is placed). The card is the container for the calculator.

```
<div class="row mt-3 mb-2">
                    <div class="col-10 offset-1"><input type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="0"></div>
                </div>
```

The calculator's output

```
<div class="p-2 mr-3">

                    <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M+</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M-</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">MC</button></div>
                    </div>
```

The first div is a wrapper for the rows that contains the buttons. I did this to apply padding and maybe margin on all of them.

Here is the full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Calculadora</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculadora.css">
</head>


<body>

    <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-xs-4">
                <div class="card container-fluid">

                    <div class="row mt-3 mb-2">
                        <div class="col-10 offset-1"><input type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="0"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-2 mr-3">

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M+</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">M-</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">MC</button></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">x^y</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">x!</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">-></button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">&lt;-</button></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">7</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">8</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">9</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">*</button></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">4</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">5</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">6</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">/</button></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">3</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">2+</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">1</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">-</button></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center my-1 mx-1">
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">.</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">0</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">=</button></div>
                            <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn">+</button></div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you post the whole HTML for the calculator? That will help to check the code :)

Comment: No problem! Its posted.

Comment: Thanks, I am adding some comments to your code and will post an answer in a minute

Comment: Oh...can you also post your `calculadora.css` file? Some classes are set there :)

Comment: I don't have any code in the css. It was from an old try to solve the problem.. I decided to try with bootstrap only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the `<main>` part again with some comments, hope it helps.

The main issue was that the buttons have a specific `width`, so they don't take all the available space in bigger screen sizes. Adding the bootstrap class `w-100` fixes that. I also made other small changes to fix alignment issues and left comments for those as well.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

```
<!--
    Display flex will make the calculator always be centered.
    You could also use position absolute or grid display.
    The height set as 100vh will make sure the container takes the
    whole screen, but you can remove that if you put this code inside
    something else.
-->
<main role="main" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
<!-- This will be the fixed size of the calculator -->
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-12">
            <!-- You already have container-fluid up there, so this is not doing much... -->
            <!-- The documentation recommends using only one container when possible -->
            <!-- Also, fluid will make the calculator grow, and you want a fixed size -->
            <div class="card">

                <!-- Added p-2 to match buttons bellow -->
                <div class="row p-2 mt-3 mb-2">
                    <!-- col-10 and offset-1 here makes the input be "smalled" than the buttons -->
                    <div class="col-12"><input type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="0"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- mr-3 here is adding a margin and making things not aligned -->
                <div class="p-2">

                    <!-- Replacing "my-1 mx-1" with "mb-2", since the columns in bootstrap already have a padding -->
                    <div class="row text-center mb-2">
                        <!-- w-100 will make the button take all the available space -->
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">M</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">M+</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">M-</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">MC</button></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-center mb-2">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">x^y</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">x!</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">-></button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">&lt;-</button></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-center mb-2">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">7</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">8</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">9</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">*</button></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-center mb-2">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">4</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">5</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">6</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">/</button></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-center mb-2">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">3</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">2+</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">1</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">-</button></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">.</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">0</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">=</button></div>
                        <div class="col-3"><button type="button" class="btn w-100">+</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- You don't need a <br> here, it is better to use margin or padding in this case -->
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Its a big improovement! Thank You!! But beyond that, i was aiming for the container fluid to keep the same size in all screens. So, for example, if the calculator has a 200px width in the small screen, i would like to maintain that for the bigger screens. The only responsiveness would be that the screen pushes the calculator to its center.